# Car park layout algorithm

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, computational-mathematics, recursive-algorithms, computational-geometry

For computer science, I need to develop a program to create a car park layout.
I am permitted to use existing algorithms, but I have not been able to find any existing solutions. Can you help me with finding a way to allocate car parking spaces in any polygon?

BONUS: A way to allocate different sizes of spaces in the given polygon, eg. one for minibuses and one for standard cars.

I understand this is a 2D version of the bin packing problem but it has the added factor that cars must be able to drive in and out of the spaces on roads.

There is no need for pedestrian paths or anything else, just a way to choose where the parking spaces and the roads will go in a given polygon of any size or number of sides.

Many thanks, Tom

Comment: Thanks Jean, any chance you could forward this question to somebody who might have a solution please?

Comment: More seriously, try to enumerate the issues. Have you made a choice for an entrance and an exit, different from the entrance ? If not, the first geometrical/computer science concept that comes to mind is a tree "rooted" at the entrance. Where has the entrance to be placed ? Maybe on the largest side of the polygon, etc.